# TFS: Branch, label or shelve?

Tags: tfs, 3-way-merge

I am pretty new to TFS but I have some experience with VSS. I like to know your opinions of what would be the best way of working with TFS in the following scenario:
We are a group of developers working on projects. All projects starts from a common base code. All projects are one man only, no code sharing until the project is done. A project can last from a few hours to several months, no code is merged until done. Any developer works simultaneously on more than one project, usually 7-10 projects at a time. Usually the projects only involve a small numbers of files that are changed/created (10-20) but rely on a large group of infrastructure files that change quite often. However, any change in infrastructure is not considered until the merge, so we don't get latest version from server until the final build.

An additional request is that, when merged, we’d like to use a 3 way merge tool. We use this approach in VSS, via a custom made application and it works very well. However this involves special file management, for example every file that has to be changed must have an original version saved somewhere that will be used as the “root” file for the 3 way merge process.

What do you think?

Comment: Can you give some more information? How many devs? how often do you release code? Do the applications have seperate development cycles? Do you have a requirement to seperate bug fixes from new functionality (and if you don't would it be a pain to change that?). FYI here is a link to some info on using a [3rd party merge tool](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmanning/archive/2006/02/20/diff-merge-configuration-in-team-foundation-common-command-and-argument-values.aspx) I like source gear diffmerge as it supports 3 way merges and is free (as in beer) but there are plenty of other options

Answer (score 4):

You should take a look at the [Visual Studio TFS Branching Guide 2010](http://tfsbranchingguideiii.codeplex.com/). ([direct download](http://tfsbranchingguideiii.codeplex.com/releases/38849/download/101774)). In that package, there is a PowerPoint deck that walks you through a series of possible branching structures.

It sounds like you want either "Branch by project" or "Branch by developer" (since you only have one developer per project, these are effectively the same).

Regarding the 3-way merge tool, take a look at this list to see [how to configure your favorite diff/merge tools](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmanning/archive/2006/02/20/diff-merge-configuration-in-team-foundation-common-command-and-argument-values.aspx).